# Health Reporting Stuck

Tags: azure-service-fabric

In a simple stateless service I am attempting to report health. As a test I am simply flipping between OK and Warning states on every iteration of my loop in RunAsync (it has a sleep interval of 15secs). The code looks like this:

```
// report warning on odd iterations
HealthState state = ((++iterations % 2) != 0) ? HealthState.Warning : HealthState.Ok;
HealthInformation health = new HealthInformation("ServiceCode", "Iteration", state);
Partition.ReportInstanceHealth(health);
```

I am logging the state on each iteration of the loop and the log shows it flipping back and forth. But in the SF Explorer it is stuck on Ok, never switching to Warning (I have a refresh interval of 5secs in SFExplorer).

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like health reporting is significantly slower than I would expect. Working on that 15sec interval was not enough time for it to show the alternating health state. Moving to a 30sec interval seems to have resolved it.

Answer (score 1):

Try specifying HealthInformation.SequenceNumber with an incremental value for every state change.